# When a normal subgroup $N$ admits a complament?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup. I am looking for conditions on $N$ (and maybe also on $G$) such that there exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that 
$$G=N\rtimes H.$$
Clearly, this is not always the case.
The easiest example for that is $C_2$ as a subgroup of $C_4$.

On the other hand, if $G$ is solvable and $N$ is a Hall normal subgroup then it admit a complament $H$ where $H$ is a Hall subgroup with order $|\frac{G}{N}|$.

I am looking for other restrictions on $N$, under such restrictions it admits a complament. Also I would be happy to see a strictly group-theoretical proof (without cohomology) of the fact that a normal Hall subgroup always admits a complament.

Comment: It is indeed true that being a normal Hall subgroup is sufficient, but given the complexity of the arguments I have seen for this (it is known as Schur-Zassenhaus), I have a feeling that you are sweeping some fairly major details under the rug in your argument.

Comment: Anyway, another possible condition is that $H$ is a cyclic $p$-Sylow for the smallest prime divisor $p$ of $G$, in which case is has a normal complement (this is the other direction though).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The proof of the existence of a complement in the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem is not too bad. You reduce to the case when $N$ is elementary abelian, and then use an averaging argument, which is equivalent to proving that the second cohomology group is trivial. But in the usual proofs that all complements are conjugate, it is necessary to assume that either $N$ or $G/N$ is solvable, and proving that needs the Feit-Thompson Theorem.

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft- Thanks for your comments, your second comment is just Burnside Normal complament theorem right? As for the first comment, I think that I have an error and the extansion must be central in order to be determined by the second cohomology group, right?

Comment: If the finite group $G$ acts on the finite module $N$ with $(|G|,|N|)=1$, then $H^n(G,N)=0$ for all $n \ge 1$. So the extension does not need to be central.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahh, I it turns out the argument I was familiar with was from a book that did things without any cohomology (and thus had to do a lot of extra work).

Comment: @DerekHolt $G$ acts on $N$, however, in order to get a $G/N$ action I need that $N$ is central, am I wrong?

Comment: You are indeed wrong! The action of $G/N$ on $N$ is induced by conjugation in $G$. You need $N$ to be abelian, but not necessarily central.

Comment: @DerekHolt you are right. So in my proof I need $N$ to be abelian or is it true as it is (not the result, the proof).

Comment: You need $N$ to be abelian for the cohomoligical argument. But the proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem does not assume that $G$ is abelian. It uses an inductive argument to reduce to that case. You should look up the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  proof of Schur-Zassenhaus, due to Wielandt, which does not make (explicit) use of group cohomology, but uses group actions instead. As has been noted in comments, it is easy to reduce to the case that $N$ is an elementary $p$-group for some  prime $p.$ Let $[G:N] = h.$
We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ of transversals to $S$ by 
$\{s_{1},\ldots,s_{h} \} \sim \{t_{1},\ldots,t_{h} \}$ if and only if $\prod_{i=1}^{h}(s_{i}t_{i}^{-1}) = 1$ (note that the order of the product does not matter, since $s_{i}t_{i}^{-1} \in N$ for each and $N$ is Abelian). We denote the equivalence class of $T$
by $[T]$. Note that $G$ acts on the equivalence classes via $T \to xT$ for $x \in G.$
The action is transitive, for given transversals $S$ and $T$ with $\prod_{i=1}^{h}(s_{i}t_{i}^{-1}) = n \in N,$ we may choose $u \in N$ with $u^{h} =n^{-1}.$ Then $T \sim uS$
since $\prod_{i=1}^{h} us_{i}t_{i}^{-1} = u^{h}n =1.$ Thus $[T] = [uS].$ In fact, we have shown that $N$ is transitive, so there are at most $|N|$ equivalence classes. Furthermore, given a transversal $S$ and $y \in N$ we have $[yS] = [S]$ if and only if $y^{h} = 1$, if and only if $y = 1$, since $h$ and $|N|$ are coprime. Thus there are exactly $|N|$ equivalence classes, and the stablizer of an equivalence class has order $[G:N]$, and is a complement to $N.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, realy nice proof.

Comment: It is due to Wielandt, as I said.